# Display data from selection in column one to column two

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have two columns. Column one (C1) is a list of countries. When an item in C1 is selected it displays the eg. cities of that country in C2.

For example,

[image: example]

How's the best way to approach this? Any tips on where to start? jQuery/Javascript, XML, tables, lists?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend jQuery click functions.  Store a related list name for each li in the rel attribute.  If each #col2 item also needs an href, etc, you can make the items in list_a and list_b arrays with multiple pieces of data.  Use CSS to syle li's accordingly.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var lists = {}; //lists container
lists.list_a = ['item 1','item 2','item 3']; //one list for each #col1 item
lists.list_b = ['item 4','item 5','item 6'];

$(function(){ //run on DOM ready

    $('#col1 li').click(function(){ //when an li from #col1 is clicked
        var list = $(this).attr('rel'); //grab it's related list
        var html = '';
        for(var i=0;i<lists[list].length;i++){ 
            html += '<li>'+lists[list][i]+'</li>'; //create li from each item in list
        }
        $('#col2').html(html); //insert new list into #col2
    });

});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="col1">
<li rel="list_a">lista</li>
<li rel="list_b">list_b</li>
</div>
<div id="col2">
</div>
</body>
```